# Which countries can I visit with my Netherlands work permit?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, spain, working-visas

I have a valid work permit in the Netherlands. And I was just asked to visit Spain to help out a client of the company.

Am I allowed to travel to Spain with my Netherlands work permit?

Comment: What specific document do you have?  A work permit allows you to work; it says nothing about your ability to be in the country.  You need a residence permit or a visa for that.  For the last year and a half or so, however, there has been a single document that serves as both a residence permit and a work permit.

Answer (score -2):

Your valid work permits allows you to visit all the countries within the Schengen Area :

```
Austria
Belgium
Czech republic
Denmark
Estonia
Finland
France
Germany
Greece
Hungary
Iceland
Italy
Latvia
Lithuania
Luxembourg
Malta
Netherlands
Norway
Poland
Portugal
Slovakia
Slovenia
Spain
Sweden
Switzerland
Liechtenstein
```

Comment: Do you have a source/reference for this?